# SHELL script to make ftp connection and get xml files

Tags: shell, ftp, connection

I need a shell script that will login to a remote FTP server, get the list of files present in only root folder and identify only xml files and get those files to local system.
Login credentials can be mentioned in the script it self. This script must be run once a day only.

Please help me with a UNIX BASH SHELL script.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVER=ftp://myserver
USER=user
PASS=password
EXT=xml
DESTDIR=/destinationdir

listOfFiles=$(curl $SERVER --user $USER:$PASS 2> /dev/null | awk '{ print $9 }' | grep -E "*.$EXT$")
for file in $listOfFiles
do
   curl $SERVER/$file --user $USER:$PASS -o $DESTDIR/$file
done
```

for scheduled run every day check the crontab:

```
crontab -e
```

for edit your current jobs and add for example:

```
0 0 * * * bash /path/to/script
```

that will mean run the script every day at midnight.

Answer (score 0):

If you can install `ncftpget`, this is a one-line operation:

```
ncftpget -u user -p password ftp.remote-host.com /my/local/dir '/*.xml'
```